# Tattooed eyeballs and wall climbing

Tags: reference, rivers-of-london

Ben Aaronovich's *Tales from the Folly* contains a short story *A Rare Book of Cunning Device* which has Peter spending the night in The British Library searching for a magical explanation for strange goings on.

It contains the following passage, which seems to be an explicit reference to another work of fiction, presumably a science fiction work, that I do not recognise. Does anyone recognise this allusion?

> Everything that wasn't painted 1970s Sci-Fi white was a brilliant red or blue, causing me to have an almost irresistible urge to tattoo my eyeball and parkour my way up the walls.

The red, blue and wall-climbing make me think of Spider-Man, but I have no idea why that would involve tattooing your eyeball.

A later passage suggests the reference might be a computer game.

> Unlike the book storage area below, which had been mainly grey and white with red trimming, the plant rooms were silver with huge cylinders painted blue, connected with yellow pipes.
> Definitely the boss level, I thought as we crept through it.

Comment: I remember some people tattooing their eyes blue to look like Fremen from Dune, but I don't see how that's connected to "brilliant red or blue" decor

Comment: The other association I had was PC Hodgell and the assassins who used *mer* for invisibility, going from cloth to tattoos, with the most senior members having their eyes tattooed to be almost entirely invisible, wall climbing/roof hopping also being a common thing in the *Kencyrath* books. But no red and blue motif, and the series is a bit obscure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I understood Peter to be referring to the [Mirror’s Edge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror%27s_Edge) series of games.

- The protagonist has a [tattooed eye](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/97/Mirror%27s_Edge.jpg)
- The gameplay involves parkour
- The game is set in a mostly white city which gets painted red or blue.

Comment: That certainly seems at least as plausible as Mario.

Comment: @Adamant - Indeed, much more plausible, although it's worth noting that it's not her eyeball that is tattooed, but rather the area *around her eye*

Comment: TV Tropes agrees with your answer; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ShoutOut/RiversOfLondon

Answer (score 2):

I think this could  be a reference to the Super Mario series of platforming games, where [jumping](https://www.mariowiki.com/Jump) is indeed Mario's main skill.

Mario wears a red and blue outfit...

[image: Image of Mario with blue overalls and a red shirt.]

In Mario's first appearance, in Donkey Kong (1981), everything had a red and blue color palette, too:

[image: Donkey Kong level]
[image: Donkey Kong poster showing Kong, Mario, and Pauline.]

In addition, his games are known to have a variety of brightly colored pipes, which fits with the second reference. In fact, the pipe theme by itself in conjunction with video game lingo would already seem like a Mario reference, even without anything else.

[image: Mario level with various pipes]

The reference to tattooing eyeballs is probably just because Peter has brown eyes, as can be seen in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/252120/51379), whereas Mario has notably bright blue ones.